# функция и его параметры

Tags: javascript

не могу найти никак ответ
помогите пожалуйста

```
let a = 0
function b(q, w, e, r, t){
 if(q > w) {
  e++
  r.textContent = e
  q = 0
  t.textContent = q
 }
}

b(a, 59, ну и так далее)
```

что я пытаюсь сделать, у меня есть блок кода, который повторяется 3 раза, вместо того, что бы писать его много раз, я хочу просто использовать 1 функцию, но вот возникает проблема, ожидаемо ничего не увеличивается, как с этим быть, как это можно исправить, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: У кого что не увеличивается?

Comment: Условие никогда не выполняется, вот ничего и не увеличивается.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo что мне нужно исправить и где, можешь подсказать?

Comment: А разве не ясно? "a" должно быть на входе больше, чем 59

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так там идет проверка, если условие не выполняется, то и работать нечему, но там др часть программы эту переменную а увеличивает, и вот когда она выше 59, то другая переменная увеличивается на единицу, а саму а сбрасывает до 0, так должно работать, как вы видите.
но у меня а не сбрасывается, а идет дальше по возрастающей, др переменная увеличивается на единицу, но изза дальнейшего сбоя работы а, она остается единицей. если быть точнее, то я делал эту функцию через замыкание

Comment: Я ничего не вижу из другой части, т.к.еë в вопросе никто не предоставил ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  .... Отладка в помощь почему что-то где-то не увеличивается